# My JavaScript source code got lost in a bad backup, trying to make sense of the if statements

Tags: javascript

My source code got lost for a project I did a year ago, so now I'm trying to restore it from the minimized Javascript. The problem is things like if statements, I don't know what the heck something like this is doing:

```
if (isFunction(action) && (action = {
        on: action
    }), actionName[actionName] || (actionName[actionName] = {}), id = index++ , actionName[actionName][id] = {
        active: typeof action.active != "undefined" ? action.active : true
    }, r.forEach(function (i) {
        action[i] && (actionName[actionName][id][i] = action[i])
    }), typeof i[actionName] != "undefined") action.on(i[actionName]);
```

I've already renamed some of the single-letter functions and variables, but I don't grok how this if statement works with the commas and setting variables inside parenthesis in the head of the if statement.

Comment: If you find the minimized code completely unrecognizable, then maybe you should not attempt to even salvage it.  If you _do_ recognize it, then consider using something like regex or an IDE to change the variable names back to their original values.

Comment: You don't know your code how it is working ! Um ...

Comment: @hs-dev2MR If I would look at a minimized version of code I wrote a year ago, then I most certainly would also have some problems in understanding certain parts. Even for not minimized code, it can be a problem.

Comment: Yeah but OP sound look like language syntax rather than logic

Comment: The minimized code is not clear at all, what I wrote was clear.

Answer (score 4):

Does not really answer the question what that `if` exactly does, but might help you throughout the whole process.

The important part is to first format the code in a way that you see the individual expressions that belong together:

```js
if (

    isFunction(action)
    && 
      (action = {
        on: action
      }), 
      actionName[actionName] || (actionName[actionName] = {}),
      id = index++, 
      actionName[actionName][id] = {
        active: typeof action.active != "undefined" ? action.active : true
      },
      r.forEach(function (i) {
        action[i] && (actionName[actionName][id][i] = action[i])
      }),
      typeof i[actionName] != "undefined"

) 
  action.on(i[actionName]);
```

The topmost expression in your `if` is the `&&`. The right side of the `&&` is only evaluated if the left side is `true`, so you can convert that to another `if` statment:

```js
if ( isFunction(action) ) {
  if(  
      (action = {
        on: action
      }), 
      actionName[actionName] || (actionName[actionName] = {}),
      id = index++, 
      actionName[actionName][id] = {
        active: typeof action.active != "undefined" ? action.active : true
      },
      r.forEach(function (i) {
        action[i] && (actionName[actionName][id][i] = action[i])
      }),
      typeof i[actionName] != "undefined"

  ) 
    action.on(i[actionName]);
}
```

So in the second `if` statement you have an expression with the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator)

> The comma operator evaluates each of its operands (from left to right) and returns the value of the last operand.

So only the last one is relevant for that `if` everything else can be moved out of the `if`, and you can get rid of those commas.

```js
if ( isFunction(action) ) {

  (action = {
    on: action
  })

  actionName[actionName] || (actionName[actionName] = {})

  id = index++

  actionName[actionName][id] = {
    active: typeof action.active != "undefined" ? action.active : true
  }

  r.forEach(function (i) {
    action[i] && (actionName[actionName][id][i] = action[i])
  })

  if( typeof i[actionName] != "undefined" ) 
     action.on(i[actionName]);
}
```

You now might continue with `actionName[actionName] || (actionName[actionName] = {})` or  `action[i] && (actionName[actionName][id][i] = action[i])` or with other parts of the code.

Answer (score -2):

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators

> The comma operator (,) simply evaluates both of its operands and returns the value of the last operand. This operator is primarily used inside a for loop, to allow multiple variables to be updated each time through the loop.

Comment: I don't understand why this was downvoted. It addresses the primary concern of OP: "I don't grok how this if statement works with the commas and setting variables inside parenthesis in the head of the if statement". If you downvote, please explain why so that I can improve the answer.

Comment: The anwswers, including this one were helpful